# "Thanks" or "thank you"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, politeness

Which one is correct — "Thank you Jim" or "Thanks Jim"?

If I start an email with the sentence "Thank you Jim" in Outlook, it shows grammar error while if I begin with "Thanks Jim" it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe the error is because you were supposed to say "Thank you, Jim."

Comment: I do noy think it is a question worth asking on El

Comment: Both are expressions of appreciation and gratitude. While the difference might be considered minimal, it still exists.
"Thanks" is more informal way of expressing gratitude. "Thanks" can also pass as slang and hence is not much stranger-friendly. It is usually used with family and friends and so it might be more commonly used than thank you due to the relationship factor. It can however, also be used sarcastically as in "Thanks for nothing”
"Thank you" is more formal but can be used with all people in both formal and informal settings. Therefore you cannot go wrong with “Thank you”.

Comment: It is the most standard form of gratitude and appreciation. It is more polite, personal and sincere and often used with someone of higher status or age. Thus it is considered to be a genuine expression of appreciation and gratitude.

Answer (score 32):

They're both correct. "Thanks" is slightly more informal, but otherwise, they both mean the same, a statement of gratitude.

Although they're both correct, they have a difference.

"Thanks" is a noun, and can be used like this:

> Give James my thanks./ I give you my thanks.(when speaking face to face)

Hence, the today's expression, "Thanks, Jim".

"Thank you", the "thank" is a verb, and is actually a shortening of the phrase "I thank you". So, you'd probably not say "Give Jim my thank-you", but "Give Jim my thanks."

Otherwise, they are interchangeable.

Comment: The grammar error that's popping up would probably be cleared by inserting a comma after "Thank you". Although the "thanks" version should probably also have a comma, it has probably been flagged as an informal usage suitable for terse communication.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: that should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: It was not a question   to  be asked on ELU which expects a lot of research , Web link, citation and so on

Answer (score 8):

*Thanks* is another way of saying *thank you*.

The difference is that *thanks* is a noun used for

- An expression of gratitude: "Festivals were held to give thanks for the harvest."
- A feeling of appreciation: "They expressed their thanks and wished her well."

*Thank* is a verb, and it means "express gratitude."